# Indeteminate While Loop

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def application():
    print("="*20)
    print("Enter 0 to multiply two numbers")
    print("Enter 1 to divide two numbers")
    print("Enter -1 to quit the application")
    print("="*20)

choice=input("Enter you choice:- ")
first_number=input("Enter 1st number:-")
second_number=input("Enter 2nd number:- ")

while choice!=-1:
    if choice==0:
        multiply=first_number*second_number
        print(str(first_number)+ " multiply by "+str(second_number)+ " is equal to " + str(multiply))
    elif choice==1:
        divide=first_number/second_number
        print(str(first_number)+ " divided by "+str(second_number)+ " is equal to " + str(divide))
    else:
        print("Invalid option.")

    application()
    choice=input("Enter your choice:- ")
print("Quit the application")
```

This is suppose to be a calculator whereby every time the user get to enter their choice however, I am having a problem. As I run this code, it only ask the user to enter their choice one time. Please give me some hint.

Comment: your input reading is before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def application():
    print("="*20)
    print("Enter 0 to multiply two numbers")
    print("Enter 1 to divide two numbers")
    print("Enter -1 to quit the application")
    print("="*20)


application() # added
choice=input("Enter you choice:- ")

while choice!=-1:

    first_number=input("Enter 1st number:-") # moved
    second_number=input("Enter 2nd number:- ") # moved

    if choice==0:
        multiply=first_number*second_number
        print(str(first_number)+ " multiply by "+str(second_number)+ " is equal to " + str(multiply))
    elif choice==1:
        divide=first_number/second_number
        print(str(first_number)+ " divided by "+str(second_number)+ " is equal to " + str(divide))
    else:
        print("Invalid option.")

    application()
    choice=input("Enter your choice:- ")

print("Quit the application")
```

---

BTW: small modifications

```
def application():
    print("="*20)
    print("Enter 0 to multiply two numbers")
    print("Enter 1 to divide two numbers")
    print("Enter -1 to quit the application")
    print("="*20)
    return input("Enter your choice:- ")

choice = application()

while choice != -1:

    if choice == 0:
        first_number = input("Enter 1st number:-") # moved
        second_number = input("Enter 2nd number:- ") # moved

        multiply = first_number * second_number
        print("%d multiply by %d equal to %s" % (first_number, second_number, multiply))
    elif choice == 1:
        first_number = input("Enter 1st number:-") # moved
        second_number = input("Enter 2nd number:- ") # moved

        divide = first_number / second_number
        print("%d divided by %d equal to %s" % (first_number, second_number, divide))
    else:
        print("Invalid option.")

    choice = application()

print("Quit the application")
```